# Is there a way to merge two dataframes using a common column and select only a few specific rows from the merged dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two dataframes on a common column, which I was able to do. Now, I want to create another dataframe containing a few specific rows of the merged dataframe in Pandas. How shall I go about this?